# Arraylist cannot be resolved to a type ? how to correct it?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList l = new Arraylist();
    l.add(10);
    l.add(10);
    l.add(null);
    System.out.println(l);
}
}
```

This code giving compile time error Exception in thread main java.lang.Error Unresolved compilation problem Arraylist cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: you are creating an arraylist that contains what type of object? If it's integers make sure in the declaration of your l object that you specify that.

Comment: it's capital `L` for `ArrayList`. As an aside, it's good practice to use generics rather than raw types.

Comment: it should be `new ArrayList()` not `Arraylist`- uppercase `l`

Comment: Got it thanks for help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collections are "generic" in nature.
You need to mention the type of objects that your collection will store.
The general syntax is:

```
 List<Type> l = new ArrayList<Type>();
```

Or

```
 List<Type> l = new ArrayList<>();
```

In your case, the Object-Type is Integer.

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
```